# How can I get the timestamp of a field in firebase cloud firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Actually I want to know the timestamp of a field which tells when the field value is updated .Can anyone guide me in this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore does not record times when fields are updated.  If you want to know that, you'll have to record it yourself in another field that you update along with the field that changed.